# How to deselect all radio button uitableview cells when button click in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, radio-button

I am displaying people's names in a UITableView with an NSMutableArray along with radio button in cell ,What I would like to know is how to make it so that when a user clicks button in navigation bar lets name it that button as clearAllButton, all of the table's contents are selected(i mean all of the radio buttons are selected), how to change the RadioButton to make it deselect all when clearAllButton clicked(I want to deselect all radioButtons when user clicks on clearAllButton).I am a new developer Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried below code in clearAllButtonAction but its does not working.

```html
- (IBAction)clearAllBtnActn:(id)sender {
    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if([btnRadio isSelected]);
    {
        [btnRadio setSelected:NO];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: show ur code...

Comment: What happend with your above code ?

Comment: please once again check my question..#Karthik

Comment: its not working #abha

Comment: u want deselect the button in all cells or just the one? does your code work for one cell?

Comment: yes i want to deselect all radioButtons when user clicks on clearAllButton.#Tj3n

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    CustomCell *cell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL b = cell.check;

    if(b)
    {
        cell.check = NO;
        [cell.Selectitems setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        cell.check = YES;

        [cell.Selectitems setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly need an underlying data source (e.g. an `NSArray` of `MyItem` objects) from which you can drive the table view cells.

Your `MyItem` object might look like this:

```
@interface MyItem ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL selected;

@end
```

Create your data source `myItems` in your view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myItems;

@end
```

In your view controller, create your cells:

```
@implementation MyViewController

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyButtonTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier@"ButtonCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    MyItem *itemForCell = myItems[indexPath.row];

    cell.titleLabel.text = itemForCell.title;
    cell.radioButton.selected = itemForCell.selected;

    return cell;
}

...

@end
```

Then your "clear" method will look like this:

```
- (IBAction)clearAllBtnActn:(id)sender {

    // Deselect all items
    for (MyItem *item in self.myItems)
        item.selected = NO;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for ur response..what you mean by MyItem??

Comment: Each cell in your table is showing data about 'something' (an item). The actual items need to be held in a model which is completely separate from your table view. You should create a class called MyItem (or whatever you want) to represent a single item. Then create an array to hold the actual data for all of your items. Read up on MVC ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) and UITableView ( https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview?language=objc)

Comment: but i didnt take any class..then what would be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

For that You have to take one array.

```
NSMutableArray *arraySelectObject;
```

Where you get the name array just call the below lines.Suppose your name array will return 5 object then,

```
arraySelectObject=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0, i<=name.count,i++)
{
   [arraySelectObject addObject:@"0"];
}
```

If you select or deselect the radio button,check the button action

```
-(IBAction)selectButton:(id)sender
{
if([arraySelectObject objectAtIndex:sender.tag]==true)
 {
   [arraySelectObject replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:@"0"];
 }
else
 {
   [arraySelectObject replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:@"1"];
 }

 [tableView reloadData];
}
```

And In your Clear ALL Button Method

```
- (IBAction)clearAllBtnActn:(id)sender 
{
    for (int i=0, i<=name.count,i++)
    {
      [arraySelectObject addObject:@"0"];
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

And in tableView cellForrow Method show the select and deselect radio button image or any code

```
if([arraySelectObject objectAtIndex:sender.tag]==true)
{
   //Set the image or your code of the select  radio button /////

}
else
{
////////// Set the image or code of the Deselect radio button ///////
}
```